# Force download for blob created with FileWriter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, filewriter

HTML5 introduces the FileWriter class. With this class you can make Blobs. (A File is an extension of a Blob.) With JavaScript you can make a Blob and for instance show it using the dataURL.

Example:

```
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append('some text')
var blob = bb.getBlob('text/plain');

var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(e) {
 document.location = this.result; // voila the dataURL
}
fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

But that's not good enough :) I want the newly created (text) file to be downloaded. Not opened in the same or a separate window.

Is there a way? There must be. How?

(The discussion already exists in the [Google Chrome group](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/msg/d98e0f6454585368?hl=en))

**UPDATE**
The File API has changed, because the specs have changed (or something!?). Webkit broke backward compatibility with `BlobBuilder`, now called `WebKitBlobBuilder`. [Same example differently on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/79JrG/)

**UPDATE**
Creating Blobs now works differently again (no more `append()`):

```
blob = new Blob(['some text'], {type: 'text/plain'});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The download tag in combination with the Blob object does the trick (at least in the latest chrome versions). See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSCJH/):

```
var blob = new Blob(['blaaaaat'], {type: 'text/plain'});
$('a').attr("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
$('a').attr("download", "woeii.txt");
```

F̶i̶r̶e̶f̶o̶x̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶s̶u̶p̶p̶o̶r̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶w̶n̶l̶o̶a̶d̶ ̶a̶t̶t̶r̶i̶b̶u̶t̶e̶  though (it does support the Blob object). Discussions about implementation of the download attribute in Firefox [are available here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619):

**Edit:** The download attribute is now supported by the latest firefox versions as of 10/3/2013

Comment: wrong fiddle link, I meant this one: http://jsfiddle.net/NSCJH/

Comment: That's the one I've been using. (I don't use Firefox.) I didn't know Firefox didn't support that yet.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea about the download attribute.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the download without waiting for the user to click the link? I have a button the user clicks that produces the data, which I want to then download immediately. Just doing $('a').click() in your fiddle didn't seem to work.

Comment: @BenDilts, just came across this answer which may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647235/897968

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **pure Javascript solution** for creating a text blob and download as text file

```
var fileContent = 'This is sample text file';
var fileName = 'sampleFile.txt';

const blob = new Blob([fileContent], { type: 'text/plain' });
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
a.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
a.click(); // EXECUTING CLICK EVENT WILL AUTO-DOWNLOAD THE FILE
```

Comment: The `download` attribute doesn't take a filename anymore. It used to, long ago, but now it's just a boolean attribute. [See MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) -- edit: or maybe it does..? I've never seen it work. Does it?

Comment: Yes it does. From the page you linked: "If the attribute has a value, it is used as the pre-filled file name in the Save prompt (the user can still change the file name if they want)."