# javascript: blob data to file

Tags: javascript, binary-data, filereader

I have a code:

```
var FReader = new FileReader();
FReader.onload = function(evnt){
  console.log(evnt.target.result);
  //How can I convert `evnt.target.result` back into a file and save it?
}

FReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Please do not offer me to use other methods. This is a very simplified code.
In the original code this data is passed to other people via websockets. And I need to transform it into files.

How can I convert `evnt.target.result` back into a file and save it?

Comment: You can submit this to the server and in turn give the response as a file back from the server

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485182/force-download-for-blob-created-with-filewriter-in-javascript

Comment: There is an API to have Save As dialog opened for a Blob, but I cannot remember it out of my head. http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side